# Instantiating boost::beast in dynamic library causes a crash

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to implement a very simple, local, HTTP server for my C++ application — I'm using XCode on macOS.  I have to implement it from within a dynamically loaded library rather than the "main" thread of the program.  I decided to try using boost::beast since another part of the application uses boost libraries already.  I'm trying to implement [this example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/beast/example/http/server/small/http_server_small.cpp), but within the context of my library, and not as part its main program.

The host application for this library calls on the following function to start a localhost server, but crashes when instantiating "acceptor":

```
extern "C" BASICEXTERNALOBJECT_API long startLocalhost(TaggedData* argv, long argc, TaggedData * retval) {
        
        try {
           
               string status;
               retval->type = kTypeString;

               auto const address = net::ip::make_address("127.0.0.1");
               unsigned short port = static_cast<unsigned short>(std::atoi("1337"));

               net::io_context ioc{1};

               tcp::acceptor acceptor{ioc, {address, port}};  // <-- crashes on this line
               tcp::socket socket{ioc};
               http_server(acceptor, socket);

               ioc.run();
               
               status = "{'status':'ok', 'message':'localhost server started!'}";
               retval->data.string = getNewBuffer(status);
               
           }
           catch(std::exception const& e)
           {
               
               string status;
               
               //err_msg = "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
               
               status = "{'status':'fail', 'message':'Error starting web server'}";
               retval->data.string = getNewBuffer(status);
               
           }

     return kESErrOK;
        
}
```

When stepping through the code, I see that XCode reports an error when the line with `tcp::acceptor ...` is executed:

`Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x783c0a3e3f22650c)`

and is highlighted at the single line of code in a function in `scheduler.h`:

```
//Get the concurrency hint that was used to initialize the scheduler.

int concurrency_hint() const
{
   return concurrency_hint_; //XCode halts here
}
```

I'm debating as to whether or not I should include a different C++ web server, like [Drogon](https://github.com/drogonframework/drogon/tree/master), instead of boost::beast, but I thought I would post here to see if anybody had any insight as to why the crash is happening in this case.

Comment: Hi! I am having the exact problem when using boost::beast in a VST plugin. Have you come up with a solution?

Comment: @caiomcg I ended up implement uWebSockets https://github.com/uNetworking/uWebSockets

Comment: @caiomcg I'm having the same issue using non-Boost ASIO with Ableton Live 11 in a VST3 on macOS. I've narrowed it down to service_registry.ipp line 131 where it is trying to create a auto_service_ptr new_service, passing in a factory method. The function pointer to the factory function points to the wrong address (or something similar, perhaps service registration fails), and the auto_service_ptr._ptr points to the incorrect object. This causes an uninitialized scheduler instance on kqueue_reactor, which is why access to scheduler_.concurrency_hint() ultimately fails with EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: @MEverett interesting findings! I could not test in other DAW because my setup only has Live Lite in it, but I can confirm that I have the same setup as yours - M1 Mac. I suspected that this could be conflicting with some implementation from Ableton since it uses Boost internally, not sure what it would be tough. I have reimplemented my code with other API which fixed things for me. I will probably go back to the issue in the near future and will look into the code you have pointed in your answer. Thank you so much for the contribution!

Comment: @ariestav I had to go through the same route and ended up using IXWebSocket: https://github.com/machinezone/IXWebSocket

Comment: @caiomcg Check out the update to my answer, I found a fix that works for me - hopefully it can work for you too.

Comment: @caiomcg If only MEverett was here early :P  Good to hear you found a lib that worked for you!

Answer (score 3):

## Update

I found a fix that is a workaround for my particular circumstances, hopefully it can help others running into this issue.

The address to the `service_registry::create` static factory method resolves correctly when I add `ASIO_DECL` in front of the methods declaration in `asio/detail/service_registry.hpp`.

It should look like this:

```
// Factory function for creating a service instance.
template <typename Service, typename Owner>
ASIO_DECL static execution_context::service* create(void* owner);
```

By adding `ASIO_DECL` in front of it, it resolves correctly and the scheduler and kqueue_reactor objects initialize properly avoiding the bad access to `concurrency_hint()`.

---

In my case I am trying to use non-Boost ASIO inside of a VST3 audio plug-in running in Ableton Live 11 on macOS on an M1 processor. Using the VST3 plug-in in  I'm getting this same crash. Using the same plug-in in other DAW applications, such as Reaper, does not cause the crash. It also does not occur for Ableton Live 11 on Windows.

I've got it narrowed down to the following issue:

In `asio/detail/impl/service_registry.hpp` the following method attempts to return a function pointer address to a create/factory method.

```
template <typename Service>
Service& service_registry::use_service(io_context& owner)
{
  execution_context::service::key key;
  init_key<Service>(key, 0);
  factory_type factory = &service_registry::create<Service, io_context>;
  return *static_cast<Service*>(do_use_service(key, factory, &owner));
}
```

Specifically, this line: `factory_type factory = &service_registry::create<Service, io_context>;`

When debugging in Xcode, in the hosts that work, when inspecting
`factory`, it shows the correct address linking to the `service_registry::create<Service, io_context>` static method.

However, in Ableton Live 11, it doesn't point to anything - somehow the address to the static method does not resolve correctly. This causes a cascade of issues, ultimately leading up to trying to invoke the `factory` function pointer in `asio/asio/detail/impl/service_registry.ipp` in the method `service_registry::do_use_service`. Since it doesn't point to a proper create method, nothing is created, it results in uninitialized objects, including the scheduler instance.

Therefore, when calling `scheduler_.concurrency_hint()` in `kqueue_reactor.ipp` the scheduler is uninitialized, and the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error results.

It's unclear to me why under some host processes, dynamically loading the plug-in cannot resolve the static method address, but others have no problem. In my case I compiled `asio.hpp` for standalone ASIO into the plug-in directly, there was no linking.

Answer (score 0):

The best guesses I can come up with are

- maybe your `http_server` might start additional threads or even fork. This might cause `io_context` and friends to be accessed after `startLocalhost` returned. To explain the crash location appearing to be at the indicated line, I could add the heuristic that something is already off during the destructor for `ioc`
- the only other idea I have is that actually the opening/binding of the acceptor throws, but due to possible incompatibilities of types in the shared module vs the main program, the exception thrown is not actually caught and causes abnormal termination. This might happen more easily if the main program also uses Boost libraries, but a different copy (build/version) of them.

  In this case there's a simple thing you can do: split up initialization and use the overloads that take `error_code` to instead use them.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I don't understand your suggestion regarding "use the overloads that take error_code to instead use them"  can you elaborate?  The main host program does use boost but am not certain which version they are.

Comment: On linux you'd use ldd, on windows you might use depenencywalker, but you can always inspect the build script to see what gets atually linked (and importantly, from where)